# How can this grammar be correct?

Tags: grammaticality

As an example sentence in the entry for fühlen in Duden there is:

> sie hat ihr Ende kommen fühlen/gefühlt

Does this mean that this sentence is correct German?

> sie hat ihr Ende kommen fühlen

If so, how can that be?